# Azure Dev Ops restrict users from accessing repositories outside the organization

Tags: azure-devops

I know there are ways using Conditional Access to limit how users can connect to Dev Ops, but is there a way to restrict users from accessing repositories shared to them by users outside the organization?

So users in the organization can only access repositories within the organization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if it's possible for restrict Dev Ops users to only have access to organization repositories only.

If there is a setting for this in Azure or Dev Ops itself.

So that organization users cannot access repositories that do not belong to the organization.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, but an external dev ops organization can share a repo to a user in my organization. Is there a setting to allow, or disallow this? So even if an external repo was shared, it cannot be accessed by users in my organization. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: It's not much of a problem a question if this feature is possible. However a company may not want their users to have any access to external repositories. Basically lock in their users to the company's repositories only. Thanks!

Comment: I understand what you **want** to do. I don't understand **why** you want to do it. Why do you care about Azure DevOps specifically, versus, say, private GitHub repos? Or public GitHub repos? Or BitBucket? Or any of the other dozens of Git hosting providers?

Comment: I care about Dev Ops specifically because it's what we use. As to why, for security purpose. A developer can pull code from our repo and push it to an external repo. I know there are many ways a developer can do this, but that is another discussion in itself :). Thanks!